# Unity How to expand a child in a horizontal layout group to the left

Tags: unity, gui

I intend to hover over an item inside a Horizontal layout group and make it expand depending on its position within the carousel. I am able to expand the items upon hovering; however, I want the items on the right to expand towards the left. How could I do so? Right now, changing the pivot of the children don't have an effect on where they should expand. They keep expanding to the right

[image]